# How do you get a single Yammer Message By ID?

Tags: yammer

Is it possible to get a Yammer Message (JSON) By ID

It seems that you should be able to do this:
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json?message_id=424641330

If you do this, it returns XML not JSON:
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/424641330

HELP!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the specific message in json without searching the thread, just use

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/[:id].json

So in your case,

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/424641330.json

Answer (score 0):

You can get a specific message by fetching that thread using thread id.
Use this:

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/threads/[:id].json

This will get the required thread with the messages in JSON form.

The endpoint you are trying to access is basically used to manipulate messages, i.e. creating or deleting a message.

I hope that helps